# Find all GameObjects in the scene containing scripts, which are derived from an abstract class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem finding all GameObjects in the scene containing scripts, which are derived from an abstract class.

Situation looks like this:

```
public abstract class IAbstractInterface: MonoBehaviour
{
}

public class Item_I_Need_To_Find1 : IAbstractInterface
{
}

public class Item_I_Need_To_Find2 : IAbstractInterface
{
}

....
```

How can I find all gameobject in the scene containing `Item_I_Need_To_Find(%number%)` scripts?

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found solution on unity answers.

`UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectsOfType< IAbstractInterface >();` worked like a charm!

Answer (score -1):

The "is" operator is your friend.

```
if (myobject is IAbstractInterface)
{
   ...
}
```